# htmlUnit after longer Javascript-Check of Bandwidth the Text-Input is not updated

Tags: javascript, java, htmlunit

On this page: https://www.check24.de/dsl/vergleich/
I tried to implement a crawler for bandwidth checks of different providers via httpUnit, version 2.31.

If you manually fill in the Address field on the page, you will see a pop-up that shows the progress of the bandwidth check, then you have the available Internet bandwidths for the requested address on the same page.
The requested address is in labels (the place where first the text input fields were.

In my attempt to write a crawler using htmlUnit, although I returned the same page after (a longer waiting time) the input field was not replaced by some label in a fieldset (id="tko-vcheck-done-wrapper") that show the address.

Here is my Code:

```
   public Map<String, Integer> checkProviderBandWidthsByAddress(String zip, String city, String street, String hno){
    WebClient webClient = null;
    try{
        webClient = getWebCient();            
        HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("https://www.check24.de/dsl/vergleich/");

        HtmlTextInput inputZipCity = (HtmlTextInput) page.getElementById("c24api_ac_widget_zipcity");
        HtmlHiddenInput inputZip = (HtmlHiddenInput) page.getElementById("c24api_ac_widget_zipcode");
        HtmlHiddenInput inputCity = (HtmlHiddenInput) page.getElementById("c24api_ac_widget_city");
        HtmlTextInput inputStreet = (HtmlTextInput) page.getElementById("c24api_ac_widget_street");
        HtmlTextInput inputStreetNumber = (HtmlTextInput) page.getElementById("c24api_ac_widget_streetnumber");
        HtmlButton buttonCheck = (HtmlButton) page.getElementById("tko-filter-vcheck-submit");

        inputZipCity.setValueAttribute(zip + " " + city);
        inputZipCity.fireEvent(Event.TYPE_INPUT);
        page.getWebClient().waitForBackgroundJavaScriptStartingBefore(1000);
        inputZip.setValueAttribute(zip);
        inputCity.setValueAttribute(city);
        inputStreet.setValueAttribute(street);
        inputStreetNumber.setValueAttribute(hno);

        page = buttonCheck.click();
        page.getWebClient().waitForBackgroundJavaScriptStartingBefore(30000);
        DomElement done = page.getElementById("tko-vcheck-done-wrapper"); // <-- Probleme here: NULL  

        List<DomElement> providers = page.getByXPath("//div[contains(@class, 'tko-result-row tko-clearfix')]");

        Map<String, Integer> bandWidths = findMaxSpeed(providers); // works fine to read the download BandWith for general tarif - but this dont contains the address-specific bandwith
        return bandWidths;
    }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return Collections.emptyMap();
    }finally {
        webClient.close();
    }
}

public static WebClient getWebCient(){
    WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_52); // also tried with Other
    webClient.setRefreshHandler(new WaitingRefreshHandler());
    webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webClient.getOptions().setCssEnabled(false);
    webClient.setCssErrorHandler(new SilentCssErrorHandler());
    webClient.setAjaxController(new NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController());
    webClient.getOptions().setUseInsecureSSL(true);
    webClient.getOptions().setRedirectEnabled(true);
    webClient.getCookieManager().setCookiesEnabled(true);
    webClient.getOptions().setPopupBlockerEnabled(false);
    return webClient;
}
```

If someone has an idea to solve the problem, I would be very happy about it

Answer (score 0):

Pages like this horrible monster are a challenge for HtmlUnit.
But if you are a bit patient, then it will work.
(I'm using HtmlUnit release 2.32)

Have added some comments to the sample code; hope that helps.
And please take the code as proof of concept, there was not enough time for writing good code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String url = "https://www.check24.de/dsl/vergleich/";

    try (final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_60)) {
        HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage(url);

        // this page has starts a lot of javascript
        // we have to wait until this is finished to get a page
        // that can respond to our typing
        wait(webClient, 60);

        HtmlTextInput inputZipCity = (HtmlTextInput) page.getElementById("c24api_ac_widget_zipcity");
        inputZipCity.type("50126");
        wait(webClient, 30);

        // System.out.println(page.getElementById("tko-result-filter-form-acsuggest").asXml());

        HtmlTextInput inputStreet = (HtmlTextInput) page.getElementById("c24api_ac_widget_street");
        HtmlTextInput inputStreetNumber = (HtmlTextInput) page.getElementById("c24api_ac_widget_streetnumber");

        inputStreet.type("Hauptstr.");
        wait(webClient, 10);

        inputStreetNumber.type("10");
        wait(webClient, 10);

        HtmlButton buttonCheck = (HtmlButton) page.getElementById("tko-filter-vcheck-submit");
        buttonCheck.click();
        wait(webClient, 4 * 60);

        HtmlPage refreshedPage = ((HtmlPage) page.getEnclosingWindow().getEnclosedPage());
        // System.out.println("----------------");
        // System.out.println(refreshedPage.asText());
        System.out.println(refreshedPage.getElementById("tko-result-sorting-text").getTextContent());
    }
}

private static void wait(WebClient webClient, int seconds) {
    long timeLimit = System.currentTimeMillis() + seconds * 1000;
    int scriptCount = webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(1000);
    while (scriptCount > 1 && timeLimit > System.currentTimeMillis()) {
        scriptCount = webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(1000);
    }

    // seems like there is always one job in the queue (maybe some kind of heartbeat)
    if (scriptCount > 1) {
        System.out.println("Still some js is running " + scriptCount);
    }
}
```

At least this produces something like

**68 Tarife verfügbar von 12,91 € bis 107,47 € (Durchschnitt pro Monat)**

Same text is shown on the web site when running with a real browser.